# "properly" Manipulate "cursor" when reading an input file when using scanners

Tags: java, cursor, textinput, cursor-position

Is this the "proper way" to pull a char and string from a line of text in a .txt input file?

```
Scanner scan, readLine;

System.out.print("Enter the name of your transaction file please (include .txt extension): ");
transFilename = scan.nextLine();
scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(transFilename));

while (scan.hasNext())
{
    // read a whole line, then use scanner to parse
    readLine = new Scanner(scan.nextLine()); 

    code = readLine.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    switch (code) {

    case 'A':
        lineinput = readLine.next();    
        filename = lineinput; 
        System.out.println(filename);    
        Scanner input = new Scanner( new FileReader(filename));

    break;

    }
```

sample input text file reads:

```
A blahblah.txt
B
A gahgah.txt
```

When this line of code runs: lineinput = readLine.next();
Does the cursor go back to the beginning of the line during that iteration of the while loop?  I just want to know how the scanner "cursor" moves through each line.

example: (^ represents the cursor position):

```
 A blahblah.txt
^
```

Answer (score 0):

On each pass through your loop, you fetch a new line from the file scanner and then create a new Scanner instance that iterates only over that line.  After `lineinput = readLine.next();`, the cursor is after the filename on the `'A'` line; however the cursor of the outer Scanner is at the beginning of the next line.